# Can't submit mac build to testflight - xcode v14.2

Tags: xcode, testflight, mac-app-store, xcode14

I am trying to submit my build for a mac os app to testflight but i get the error -

> This build is using a beta version of Xcode and can’t be submitted.
> Make sure you’re using the latest version of Xcode or the latest seed
> release found on the releases tab in News and Updates

I am using Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18), I am not sure if its beta, but it is the latest one available in the app store.

Do I need to downgrade to some previous version or there is some other issue? Thanks.

Comment: The target of your communication should be Apple, not us. Even better, just wait 48 hours and try again; Apple does suffer little server glitches from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging I found the issue. My Info.plist file was missing several metadata info like -

```
<key>DTXcode</key>
<string>1331</string>
<key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
<string>13E500a</string>
```

After adding those testflight accepted the build.